# No me muestra todos los registros de mi BDD en C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, windows-forms

!Buenas!

Tengo una base de datos con pocos datos introducidos. Estoy intentando traer esos datos y mostrarlos "ordenados" en un `textbox`. Pero solo me muestra el ultimo registro y ademas el salto de linea no esta funcionando, me lo escribe todo seguido.

**¿Que podría ser?**

Aquí tengo el código:

```
//BOTON OK.
private void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmd.CommandText = ("select * from tarea where @ID = id_agenda");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", buscarID.Text);
    MySqlDataReader registro = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (registro.Read())
    { 
        textBox4.Text = ($"ID: {registro["id_agenda"].ToString()}\nLugar: {registro["lugar"].ToString()}\n" +
            $"Fecha: {registro["dia"].ToString()}/{registro["mes"].ToString()}\nHora: {registro["hora"].ToString()}\n" +
            $"Descripcion: {registro["descripcion"].ToString()}"); 
    }

    registro.Close();
}
```

Trato de hacer que al pulsar el `button`compare el ID que ha introducido el usuario con los registros de la BDD y me los muestre, pero solo lo hace con el ultimo registro.

Comment: Una pregunta, quieres obtener **todos**  los registros de la BD, o solamente el **primero**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el filtro que aplicas deberia devolver un solo registro entronces deberias usar el `if` en lugar del `while`

```
private void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string query = "select * from tarea where @ID = id_agenda";
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conexion))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", buscarID.Text);

        MySqlDataReader registro = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (registro.Read())
        { 
            List<string> lineas = new List<string>();
            lineas.Add($"ID: {registro["id_agenda"].ToString()}");
            lineas.Add($"Lugar: {registro["lugar"].ToString()}");
            lineas.Add($"Fecha: {registro["dia"].ToString()}/{registro["mes"].ToString()}");
            lineas.Add($"Hora: {registro["hora"].ToString()}");
            lineas.Add($"Descripcion: {registro["descripcion"].ToString()}");

            textBox4.Lines = lineas.ToArray();
        }
    }

}
```

El TextBox de por si no muestra multiline sino asignas la propiedad, asigna la propiedad `Multiline` en `true`

[TextBox.Multiline](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.multiline?view=netframework-4.8)

[TextBox.Lines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines?view=netframework-4.5#System_Windows_Forms_TextBoxBase_Lines)

Recomiendo que los objetos de conexion a la db no sean globales, define el SqlCommand local donde lo necesites utilizar, definiendolo dentro del `using` para que se libere correctamente

Comment: La verdad es que no me queda clara tu respuesta. Según la pregunta, lo que quiere  @Youshiro es obtener **todos** los registros de la BD, y con tu ejemplo solo se obtiene el primero. No me aclaro... o igual yo no he entendido bien la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema radica en que cada vez que lees un registro del `SqlDataReader` y lo asignas al TextBox `textBox4`, estás **sobrescribiendo** el valor del anterior registro.

Si lo que quiere es que todos los registros se muestren en **un único** TextBox (`textBox4`) debes ir "concatenándolos" (+=):

```
textBox4.Text += ($"ID: {registro["id_agenda"].ToString()}\nLugar: {registro["lugar"].ToString()}\n" +
        $"Fecha: {registro["dia"].ToString()}/{registro["mes"].ToString()}\nHora: {registro["hora"].ToString()}\n" +
        $"Descripcion: {registro["descripcion"].ToString()}");
```

Por otra parte tu TextBox debe ser multilínea (`TextBox.Multiline = true;`)